# USB to USB mimicking Ethernet?

Tags: networking, usb, ethernet

I know it's possible to connect a computer to a wireless adapter via ethernet and/or USB, likewise for the Raspberry Pi. Is it possible to connect my (Ubuntu) laptop to my Raspberry Pi via a double male USB cable and make them talk like it's an ethernet cable? Also, obviously, if it's possible how do I do it?
I've been trying to find an answer and I'm having no luck.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: As lenik points out, you CANNOT do this with a normal usb cable.  Essentially: when you plug a USB cable in, it is not a parallel relationship.  The host adapter in the computer expects there to be a (slave) device on the other end.  If you plug that into another computer, its host adapter is doing the same thing -- looking for a slave.  There is *no way* out of that using just software, which is why they make those special USB-USB cables: notice there is some hardware in the middle to handle the relationship.  That's a slave device for the two adapters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to use RNDIS drivers for that purpose, but there are better alternatives available today: http://www.linux-usb.org/usbnet/

Usbnet support is supposed to be included in the latest kernels.

Comment: I've stumbled across this page a few times in my search but unfortunately I'm not savvy enough to fully understand it. I can follow it mostly but I'm still not sure how exactly I can use this to achieve my goal. Also, I'm not using one of those funky transfer cables mentioned in the document. I just want to use a plain USB cable with two male ends. I figure it will require configuration on the Pi, but I'm not sure what configurations are needed.

Comment: Doesn't that require that at least one of the two ends support USB host mode?

Comment: @FatalKeystroke you may not use two HOST USB endpoints, they won't be able to talk to each other. therefore you need a special cable, that looks like a slave or peripheral to each host.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen if you have only one host, you don't need fancy cables -- it will work straight from the box. however, connecting two hosts (like RasPi and another PC) is tricky.

Comment: @lenik ok, then my question is, doesn't it require that at least one of the two ends support USB slave mode? (or USB-to-go?)

Comment: Could you expand on your answer. I am quite interested in how that works? An example, reference or video that it will work with a Pi? Otherwise we might be shooting in the dark :(

Answer (score 3):

This is only possible with the model A/A+ hardware, which is capable of both host and device mode on the single USB port it has. However, it doesn't currently work due to kernel bugs[1](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/881),[2](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/882),[3](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/883),[4](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/884).

If device mode did work, then you could use the gadget drivers such as g_ether, which would make the model A appear as a USB ethernet device when connected to a PC with a double male cable.

Comment: This would be very interesting for the #pizero to hook up a bunch of them behind a device with ethernet (a Pi 2 perhaps). Is there any chance of getting these bugs fixed soon?

Comment: I don't know, but I hope so.